# Generate diagram from Django Model with dragable elements

Tags: django-models, uml, dot, database-diagram

how is it possible to generate Django Model diagram with dragable elements. Have tried to generate diagram of Django model from .dot file created using py manage.py graph_models, I got the diagram using .dot file but its elements are static how to make them dragable[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorv3.jpg), thanks.

Comment: You mean in that specific tool? Which one is it?

Comment: I use https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html to generate .dot file for Django model that describes its structure  and than would like to generate diagram from that file that has dragable tables (bacause I would like to save it in my report in a4 sheet it helps to save room, auto generated diagram take to much room between tables)

Comment: that extension allows to indicate which elements must be exported rather than to get all, did you used that way ?

Comment: I use it to generate .dot file and the try to do diagram from it using http://graphviz.it/#/gallery/rowe.gv but it is static and impossible to drag elements tables and connectors